# How do I solve the "missing associated type `Err` value" error?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a simple utility function that reads multiple elements from `stdin` and puts them in collection and returns it. However I'm stuck at this point. The compiler says `missing associated type Err value`. How do I make it work, while keeping it generic as possible?

While this function seems useless, it's for learning the language and its type system.

```
use std::io::{ stdin };
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::io::Read;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

pub fn read_all<C>() -> C
    where C: FromIterator<FromStr<Err>>
{
    let mut buff = String::new();
    stdin().read_to_string(&mut buff).expect("read_to_string error");
    buff.split_whitespace()
        .filter_map(|w| w.parse().ok())
        .collect()
}
```

Usage example:

```
let v: Vec<i32> = read_all();
```

Comment: Just added some words about the relation between types and traits, in case you are interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Working code

The only thing you need to change to your code in order to make it compile is the type signature of the function:

```
pub fn read_all<C, F>() -> C
    where F: FromStr,
          C: FromIterator<F>
```

### Explanation

Your code is almost correct, but there is a problem:

- `FromIterator<T>` is a trait, but `T` is a **type**.
- You use `FromStr` in the place of `T`, but `FromStr` is a **trait**, not a type.

To solve this, you need to get a **type** that implements `FromStr`. You can do this by adding a type parameter `F` to the function and constraining it with `where F: FromStr`. Then you can write `FromIterator<F>`.

### A note on associated types

Besides the issue of using a trait instead of a type, typing `FromStr<Err>` is wrong syntax. While in this case it is not necessary to specify the type of `Err` in the `FromStr` trait, you could do it as shown below:

```
pub fn read_all<C, F, E>() -> C
    where F: FromStr<Err=E>,
          C: FromIterator<F>
```

As you can see, instead of writing `FromStr<E>` we need to write `FromStr<Err=E>`. That is, you need to explicitly type the name of the associated type you are referring to.

### A note on types vs traits

Usually traits cannot be treated as types. However, there are exceptions to this rule, as illustrated by the example below:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

pub fn print_box(thing: Box<Display>) {
    println!("{}", thing)
}

fn main() { print_box(Box::new(42)); }
```

Here, you would expect `T` in `Box<T>` to be a type, but the `Display` trait is supplied instead. However, the compiler does not reject the program. The type checker sees `Display` as an [unsized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsized-types.html). That is, the type of an object with a size unknown at compile time (because it could be any type implementing `Display`). When `T` in `Box<T>` is a trait, the resulting type is usually referred to as a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html). It is impossible to cover this topic in depth here, but the links I refer to are a good starting point in case you want to know more.

Comment: You beat me to it. I [had the Playground example ready to go as well](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=3a8435a25c3a22f23d3585f4abb3f2bb&version=stable). Oh well :)